# Pulling an Docker Image within a chroot environment

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, chroot

I am trying to create my own, custom Raspberry Pi image using Pi-Gen https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen Basically I was able to fulfill most of my requirements, but I got a problem while trying to install HomeAssistant using their install script.

As you can see in the above-mentioned git repo, Pi-Gen uses a staging system. Every stage contains scripts that get executes on the destination chroot. I already installed docker that way. For installing HomeAssistant, I have copied this script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-assistant/supervised-installer/master/installer.sh to the destination chroot. Then I executed it with this command:

Now the problem is, that inside of this install script, i try to pull a docker image into the virtual chroot environment.

This leads to this error:

```
[Info] Install supervisor Docker container"
time="2020-05-01T09:38:10+01:00" level=error 
msg="failure getting variant" 
error="getCPUInfo for pattern: Cpu architecture: not found"
```

Docker seems not to have any information about the CPU inside the chroot environment. 
Is there any workaround for that problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Before entering chroot (or running the script that enters chroot), bind the **/proc** directory on top of your chroot base path so docker can "see" **/proc/cpuinfo** on the host OS.

```
mount -o bind /proc ./mychrootbasepath/proc
```

Comment: I messed around a bit before finding ho to remove it : `umount proc` obviously