# Fake /proc/cpuinfo when using chroot

Tags: chroot

I am trying to install some software using chroot for a Rpi image (pi-gen). 
Pi-Gen uses chroot to install them.

Unfortunately when executing

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

under chroot environment, i get the cpuinfo from my host system. 
But for successfull installation of my desired software, cpuinfo must output the infors of the target system. How can i fake the cpuinfo file?

I have already tried to overwrite the file inside of the chroot env. But this leads me to a "not permited" error.

Thanks

Comment: And what is the host system? An x86 PC? // Also, what _exactly_ are you trying to install and how?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The target system is a Rasperry Pi arm7l. I try to generate my own image using https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen. With this i want to install HomeAssistant inside of the chroot environment. HomeAssistant consists of several containers. I already installed docker into chroot. Now i want to pull the appropriate docker images. Docker complained about missing cpuInfo. Therefore i want to try this approach. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1547606/pulling-an-docker-image-within-a-chroot-environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the file to a regular filesystem, edit according to your needs, then `mount --bind` the edited file over the original.

```
mount --bind /tmp/cpuinfo.txt /proc/cpuinfo
```

It'll only lie to the software – it won't actually make the CPU *capable* of running the software if it isn't.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Maybe you know, why curl doesnt work when used inside chroot?

Comment: @C.Hediger If you have a separate question then [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).